# Cannot restrict apps from accessing data in iOS 8

Tags: iphone, cellular-data, ios

I cannot restrict apps from accessing cellular data on iOS 8, as these settings are disabled. How can I enable them?

[image: this is the settings screen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found why I cannot change any option in this section. This happened because of the restrictions that where activated after the update to iOS 8. In order to solve it go to General->Restrictions->cellular data use-> Allow changes

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict apps from using Cellular Data on iOS8. Just switch on your cellular data first, only then will you be allowed to restrict or allow applications to access the data.

**Edit** : Apparently, the restriction is enabled automatically for cellular data by default after the update. Remove the restriction to restrict the apps.

Comment: This screenshot is taken with cellular data on so I can't restrict or allowed apps access the data

Comment: Even if data is enabled the section with the apps is grey and I am unable to change any option

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.. There is a restrictions option that restricts changing cellular data settings.Turn that off and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Once you open each application using cellular date (when you're not connected to wifi) the option to restrict data use will appear